# how to print Statement (CallableStatement) in Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

How can I print this OracleCallableStatement ?

```
   ocstmt = (OracleCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall("{?= call 
            package.method(id => ?, name=>?)}");
   ocstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);            
   ocstmt.setInt(2, obj.getId());
   ocstmt.setString(3, obj.getName());
   ocstmt.execute();
   resultSet = ocstmt.getCursor(1);
```

What I mean is how can I know that what query goes to the database, how can I print the query? because sometimes it gives me error like "Wrong type" that is why I want to look at this query

Answer (score 5):

Are you using log4j?

If so, add loggers for sql like below.

```
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG
```

If you are using a ORM framework such as ibatis, you could add additional logger like below.

```
log4j.logger.com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientDelegate=DEBUG
```

Comment: The actual behavior depends on the support of the underlying driver.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this.  You can either wrap your callable statement in a proxy that can substitute the actual values when you print it (and show the sql), or hunt around for a driver that has a meaningful toString.  [javaworld article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905213127/http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073957/testing-debugging/overpower-the-preparedstatement.html) There is also [p6spy](https://web.archive.org/web/20090316195712/http://andykayley.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-print-out-bind-variables-in-java.html), and others.
Stored procedures are harder, but still doable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the SQL by printing the Statement.

Is the example you posted one of the "sometimes" that triggers the error?

Why do you have to case this to an OracleCallableStatement?  What part of the call is not the standard CallableStatement?

Comment: I give my 10 minutes to wrong type sent int instead of double. That is why I want to get sql before execute() it

Comment: "*you can't*" is not quite correct. It depends on the underlying JDBC driver and thus the actual implementation of the `Statement` interface. Some drivers to implement a proper `toString()` method, some don't. Oracle does not however.

Comment: All the ones I commonly use don't as far as I know (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, some PostgreSQL).  Can you name some that do?

Comment: Yes, custom ones, or p6spy or a custom wrapper.  And it IS an extremely useful technique.  Why doesn't my SQL work?  Because you fed it garbage, AND.... this is the garbage you gave it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, use myObject.toString() to see what it prints. You may or may not be able to see the full query though. If you can't get it to go, the first thing that I would look at is the API documentation(javadocs for that Oracle library or driver that you're using)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but it seems like you want to see this:

```
  String sql = "{?= call package.method(id => ?, name=>?)}";
  System.out.println(sql);
  ocstmt = (OracleCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall(sql);
  ...
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I want to print the sql query which goes to the database with the values. "Insert into table values('a', 1, 11.23.2010)"

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use [proxy jdbc driver](http://code.google.com/p/jdbcdslog-exp) to log all jdbc database actions.
this driver can prints all statements with values and all results.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is use **ProxyDataSourceBuilder**(use it in Spring Boot project).

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    SLF4JQueryLoggingListener loggingListener = new SLF4JQueryLoggingListener();
    return ProxyDataSourceBuilder
            .create(datasource)
            .listener(loggingListener)
            .build();
}
```

...

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
ocstmt = (OracleCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall("{?= call 
        package.method(id => ?, name=>?)}");
```

And just turn on logging in application.yml:

```
logging: 
    level:
      net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener.logging: debug
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 > java -classpath ojdbc8.jar oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql false false "<your sql here>"
```

That will print the SQL that the driver sends to the database, among other things. This is not documented nor supported, but it's been around forever.

Answer (score -5):

I thought it might be useful if you are looking whether executed query has value or not

```
System.out.println("value : "+CallableStatement.execute());
```

i.e The "false" returned by "CallableStatement.execute()" means that the JDBC statement didn't read any rows, (so there's no ResultSet to read). This is what you'd expect, as stored procedures don't directly return ResultSets, they only return values for any OUT or INOUT parameters.