# java CallableStatement print all parameters in procedure

Tags: java, jdbc

```
CallableStatement stmt =  getSession().connection().prepareCall(
                "{call CRM_DAO.Search_Customers(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

setString(1, filter.getFirstname(), stmt);
....
stmt.execute();
```

Can I somehow see all input parameters that I can execute this procedure in SQL and not manually check all partameters?

I want to get back something like:

```
call CRM_DAO.Search_Customers(1, 3, 'test',..
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657349/how-to-print-statement-callablestatement-in-java

Comment: Your question is very unclear; what is it *exactly* that you're trying to do?

Comment: JDBC doesn't mandate any such support, because in most implementations, query text and parameters never end up together on execute (the query is prepared, and on execute only the parameter values are sent).

Answer (score 1):

I use log4jdbc for this purpose.  Works great and very easy to configure.  If you drop it in and use it as your jdbc driver it will auto-wrap most jdbc-compliant drivers.

https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/

It can be a little chatty, but the log-levels are configurable and broken into sub-categories to help narrow down what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to better define what you mean by "somehow see all input parameters". Your best bet would be to use the `getXXX` methods on the `Statement` object and see exactly which values have been placed for each parameter - but, from the way that you phrased your question, it seems like this is precisely what you *don't* want to do.

**EDIT** *as per OP's comment, the objective is to see exactly what statement exactly is being executed*

There is no standard way of doing so in JDBC. If your intention is to have these "expanded" statements printed out to the log, then you will have to resort to logging/tracing methods that *may* be available by your JDBC driver's provider or your JEE container. If your intention is to receive those statements as a `String` within your program, then perhaps you should follow @jgitter's advice, download `log4jdbc`'s source code and see how they go about printing the statement (I wouldn't be surprised if it turns out that they simply use the various `getXXX` methods on the `Statement` object).

Comment: I have ParameterMetaData but i can not see values in it

Comment: One such way of handling this is using a proxy driver that logs your desired parameters.  Check out my answer for more info on one such proxy called log4jdbc.